# Trying to add 'Free Delivery' badge to product thumbnail in Woocommerce based on shipping class

Tags: php, woocommerce

I wanted to add a 'Free UK Delivery' text badge to products that do not have a shipping class associated with them.  This is the very rough code I have so far but this is a new language to me and I'm trying to splice things together and not succeeding very well.  Would super appreciate some help:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10 );
function single_product_label() {
    global $product;

    if( $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class() ) {
    if ( $shipping_class->is_wp_error) {
              echo '<span class="freedel">Free UK Delivery</span>';
      }
    }
    return '';
  }
```

and CSS code:

```
.freedel {
padding: 3px 8px;
text-align: center;
background: #222;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
right: 6px;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Emma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has errors in it. You can change it to the following

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'single_product_label', 10 );
function single_product_label() {
    global $product;
    if ( empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        echo '<span class="freedel">Free UK Delivery</span>';
    }
  }
```

I have done a quick check and this shows the label. See the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  Really appreciate you taking the time to look at my code - works perfectly now!